# Ensure that previously "Google penalized" domain is okay to use

Tags: seo, google-penguin-algorithm

**Background**
My client's previous SEO team used link farming to increase the rank of the old domain. Due to this, the site was penalized by Google.

When we took over, the old domain seemed completely un-indexed; the site wasn't returned in any searches whatsoever.

In response, we created a site at a new domain; this new site is indexed and searchable, but still has years of previous SEO to make up.

Recently, however, the old domain became searchable again somehow.

---

**Questions**

- Is it safe to upload the new site at the old domain?
- How can I ensure that the link farm links don't point to the old domain anymore?
- How can I ensure that the old site's penalty won't affect the site in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answers**

- Of course it's safe. Will Google penalize it for being on the old domain? Hard to tell, though if it's being indexed again, chances are it's safe. The thing about link farms is they're rarely long term, let alone permanent. As more natural looking links start to outweigh farmed links, it's not uncommon to start indexing again. You can actually check Google Webmaster Tools to see what links are coming in and "Disavow" certain links, so that Google won't take them into consideration when ranking.
- Webmaster Tools. Look at your incoming links, disavow any that you dont want there. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en
- Really, you cant. It's trial and error at this point. On one side, if you take the risk and run the old domain, you can come out ahead because of its age. On the other hand, if you run the old domain and it's being penalized, you could come out behind and end up losing rank. It's a gamble. You could try split testing the domains to see how they're performing, so that you could focus more efforts on one.